# Installing and using cURL in Linux and use it in Eclipse as well?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, eclipse, curl

I come from a Windows environment - I used [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) in Eclipse (C). I want to do the same in a Linux environment (Ubuntu). I followed the [installation guide](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) on how to install cURL, but how do you use cURL from Eclipse once it is installed?

Comment: Update: I followed the tutorial (goo.gl/vNrYxl): I got the required include path from terminal: $ curl-config --cflags - it returned: I/usr/local/include. I included this path in Eclipse: Project Properties-> C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Includes Tab. I located the required libraries with $ curl-config --libs and it returned -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl. I linked the libs in Eclipse: Project Properties-> C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->Libraries tab. (Specifically: libcurl.a). When I build the project it reports an error: "cannot find -l/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a. Ideas?

Comment: Please show us what you have entered in eclipse Libraries

Answer (score 1):

Isn't enough to do `apt-get install curl`?

After that you can use it:

```
curl http://www.google.com
```

If you are more after using libcurl then you should ask in stackoverflow.com

If you install it from the source you will need to setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  to point to directory where you have libcurl.

Comment: I want to access libcurl functions within eclipse and not the terminal. I can confirm that curl has been sucessfully installed in Linux. By the way, I posted the question originally on Stack Exchange, but they put it on hold and suggested Superuser...